# MySQL - get booking reservations according to dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all the booking reservations according to `date_begin` and `date_end` fields. I have a calendar which only shows 10 days of the selected date calendar.

```
2017-05-15    -> Date chosen by user
2017-05-10    -> Date begin
2017-05-20    -> Date end
```

And currently my query is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings
WHERE ((date_begin >= '2017-05-10' AND date_begin <= '2017-05-20') OR 
       (date_end >= '2017-05-10' AND date_end <= '2017-05-20'))
```

Now, what happens is that 90% of my reservations do show on the calendar and works, but there's one **if**.

If the reservation is longer than 10 days (which is the limit of the calendar) it will only show in the calendar if:

1. The `date_begin` exists in the calendar OR
2. The `date_end` exists in the calendar

Which means there's a gap in the calendar, between some dates.

```
2017-05-15    -> Date chosen by user
2017-05-10    -> Date begin
2017-05-20    -> Date end
2017-05-11    -> Date begin reservation
2017-05-27    -> Date end reservation
Shows in calendar? Yes

2017-05-16    -> Date chosen by user
2017-05-11    -> Date begin
2017-05-22    -> Date end
2017-05-11    -> Date begin reservation
2017-05-27    -> Date end reservation
Shows in calendar? Yes

2017-05-17    -> Date chosen by user
2017-05-12    -> Date begin
2017-05-23    -> Date end
2017-05-11    -> Date begin reservation
2017-05-27    -> Date end reservation
Shows in calendar? No!

2017-05-18    -> Date chosen by user
2017-05-13    -> Date begin
2017-05-24    -> Date end
2017-05-11    -> Date begin reservation
2017-05-27    -> Date end reservation
Shows in calendar? No!

2017-05-21    -> Date chosen by user
2017-05-16    -> Date begin
2017-05-27    -> Date end
2017-05-11    -> Date begin reservation
2017-05-27    -> Date end reservation
Shows in calendar? Yes
```

How can I improve my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do  this.

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings
WHERE date_begin <= '2017-05-20' AND date_end >= '2017-05-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Linesofcode-
This discussion about 
[datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/4970355) should work.
 `(StartDate1 <= EndDate2) and (StartDate2 <= EndDate1)`

Thanks to Ian Nelson